# Can I retrieve objects with Sequel from a complex query that limits results to fields from a single table?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a model whose rows I always want to sort based on the values in another associated model and I was thinking that the way to implement this would be to use `set_dataset` in the model. This is causing query results to be returned as hashes rather than objects, though, so none of the methods from the class can be used when iterating over the dataset.

I basically have two classes

```
class SortFields < Sequel::Model(:sort_fields)
    set_primary_key :objectid
end

class Items < Sequel::Model(:items)
    set_primary_key :objectid
    one_to_one :sort_fields, :class => SortFields, :key => :objectid
end
```

Some backstory: the data is imported from a legacy system into mysql. The values in `sort_fields` are calculated from multiple other associated tables (some one-to-many, some many-to-many) according to some complicated rules. The likely solution will be to just add the values in `sort_fields` to `items` (I want to keep the imported data separate from the calculated data, but I don't have to). First, though, I just want to understand how far you can go with a dataset and still get objects rather than hashes.

If I set the dataset to sort on a field in `items` like so

```
class Items < Sequel::Model(:items)
    set_primary_key :objectid
    one_to_one :sort_fields, :class => SortFields, :key => :objectid
    set_dataset(order(:sortnumber))
end
```

then the expected clause is added to the generated SQL, e.g.:

```
>> Items.limit(1).sql
=> "SELECT * FROM `items` ORDER BY `sortnumber` LIMIT 1"
```

and queries still return objects:

```
>> Items.limit(1).first.class
=> Items
```

If I order it by the associated fields though...

```
class Items < Sequel::Model(:items)
    set_primary_key :objectid
    one_to_one :sort_fields, :class => SortFields, :key => :objectid
    set_dataset(
        eager_graph(:sort_fields).
        order(:sort1, :sort2, :sort3)
    )
end
```

...I get hashes

```
?> Items.limit(1).first.class
=> Hash
```

My first thought was that this happens because all fields from `sort_fields` are included in the results and maybe if selected only the fields from `items` I would get `Items` objects again:

```
class Items < Sequel::Model(:items)
    set_primary_key :objectid
    one_to_one :sort_fields, :class => SortFields, :key => :objectid
    set_dataset(
        eager_graph(:sort_fields).
        select(:items.*).
        order(:sort1, :sort2, :sort3)
    )
end
```

The generated SQL is what I would expect:

```
>> Items.limit(1).sql
=> "SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` LEFT OUTER JOIN `sort_fields` ON (`sort_fields`.`objectid` = `items`.`objectid`) ORDER BY `sort1`, `sort2`, `sort3` LIMIT 1"
```

It returns the same rows as the `set_dataset(order(:sortnumber))` version but it still doesn't work:

```
>> Items.limit(1).first.class
=> Hash
```

Before I add the sort fields to the `items` table so that they can all live happily in the same model, is there a way to tell Sequel to return on object when it wants to return a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `#eager_graph`, you must use `#all` instead of `#each` to retrieve the results in order for the graph to be processed (since you cannot eagerly load without having all instances up front), or use the `eager_each` plugin (which makes `#each` call `#all` internally).

Comment: Ah... `items.first` returns a `Hash`, `Items.all.first` returns an `Items`. That's going to be pretty inefficient, then, if all I'm trying to do is order the results?

Comment: If all you want to do is order and it is causing a bottleneck, you can probably just do a join manually or call `ungraphed.select_all(:items)` after the eager_graph call.